# Binary search in Rust

Tags: rust

I am a newbie to rust and wanted to know if this code is following idiomatic rust or can be improved.

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;


pub fn find(array: &[i32], key: i32) -> Option<usize> {
    if array.is_empty(){
        return None;
    }
    let mut start = 0;
    let mut end = array.len() - 1;
    let mut middle;

    loop {
        middle = (end - start) / 2;
        let middle_element = array[start + middle];
        match key.cmp(&middle_element){
            Ordering::Less => end -= middle,
            Ordering::Greater => start += middle,
            Ordering::Equal => {return Some(start+middle as usize);} ,
        }

        //The slicing syntax produces an unborrowed slice
        //(type: [i32]) which we must then borrow (to give a &[i32]),
        //even if we are slicing a borrowed slice.//More can be read at
        //https://github.com/nrc/r4cppp/blob/master/arrays.md
        if end - start <= 1 {
            break;
        };
    }

    if array[start] == key {
        return Some(start as usize);
    }

    if array[end] == key {
        return Some(end as usize);
    }

    None
}
```

It has passed all the tests listed on Exercism for binary_search problem.

Answer (score 4):

### Style

#### Spaces and punctuation

```
if array.is_empty(){
```

should be

```
if array.is_empty() {
```

(likewise `match key.cmp(&middle_element){` → `match key.cmp(&middle_element) {`, etc.)

```
Ordering::Equal => {return Some(start+middle as usize);} ,
```

should be

```
Ordering::Equal => return Some(start + middle as usize),
```

although really, the comma at the end isn't necessary; you can remove that too.

And there should only be one new line below `use std::cmp::Ordering` and none above.

#### Scope

`middle` isn't used outside the `loop`, so you can replace:

```
let mut middle;

loop {
    middle = (end - start) / 2;
```

with:

```
loop {
    let middle = (end - start) / 2;
```

Note how the `mut` can go away, because the value of `middle` is only set once (per loop).

#### Unnecessary cast (`as`)

```
Ordering::Equal => {
    return Some(start + middle as usize);
},
```

The `as usize` is unnecessary; Rust already knows that you're returning `Option<usize>`. In fact, both `start` and `middle` are already `usize`, as is `start + middle`, so Rust isn't even doing anything fancy to get this to work. However, writing `as usize` makes it *seem* like those *aren't* `usize`, which could end up confusing your reader quite a lot.

(Same with `start as usize` → `start` and `end as usize` → `end`.)

#### Misleading comments

This comment:

```
//The slicing syntax produces an unborrowed slice
//(type: [i32]) which we must then borrow (to give a &[i32]),
//even if we are slicing a borrowed slice.//More can be read at
//https://github.com/nrc/r4cppp/blob/master/arrays.md
if end - start <= 1 {
```

is misleading, for two reasons:

- It's right above (hence attached to) the wrong piece of code.
- You don't use the slicing syntax (`array[4..6]`) anywhere in your code; you use the *indexing* syntax.

Just remove it; perhaps replace it with

```
let middle_element = array[start + middle];
// cmp requires a reference
match key.cmp(&middle_element) {
```

or something if you think it would be helpful. Though be aware that `let middle_element = array[start + middle]` makes a copy of `middle_element`, so the reference is to `middle_element` on the stack, not `array[start + middle]` wherever `array` is stored.

#### `loop` with `if` and `break`

```
if end - start <= 1 {
    break;
};
```

You're trying to make a `do` `while` loop here. However, if `end - start <= 1` already, *you don't need to enter this `loop` in the first place*. This means you can just use a regular `while`:

```
while end - start > 1 {
    let middle = (end - start) / 2;
    let middle_element = array[start + middle];
    // cmp requires a reference
    match key.cmp(&middle_element) {
        Ordering::Less => end -= middle,
        Ordering::Greater => start += middle,
        Ordering::Equal => return Some(start + middle),
    }
}
```

And now `cargo fmt` doesn't change the code, and `cargo clippy` doesn't give any suggestions. Hooray!

### Implementation

#### `middle`

In my mind, `middle` should be the index of the middle element – not the difference between `start` and the middle element. You might want to calculate this as `(start + end) / 2` but that risks overflow; fortunately, `start + (end - start) / 2` works fine.

So this:

```
let middle = (end - start) / 2;
let middle_element = array[start + middle];
// cmp requires a reference
match key.cmp(&middle_element) {
    Ordering::Less => end -= middle,
    Ordering::Greater => start += middle,
    Ordering::Equal => return Some(start + middle)
}
```

becomes:

```
while end - start > 1 {
    let middle = start + (end - start) / 2;
    let middle_element = array[middle];
    // cmp requires a reference
    match key.cmp(&middle_element) {
        Ordering::Less => end = middle,
        Ordering::Greater => start = middle,
        Ordering::Equal => return Some(middle)
    }
}
```

#### Unnecessary variable

Now we've made that change, I think `array[middle]` is obviously the middle element; so much so that we can remove `middle_element` entirely and get clearer code:

```
let middle = start + (end - start) / 2;
// cmp requires a reference
match key.cmp(&array[middle]) {
```

#### `Ordering` ordering

I actually think it'd be clearer if these were in `Less`, `Equal`, `Greater` order:

```
match key.cmp(&array[middle]) {
    Ordering::Less => end = middle,
    Ordering::Equal => return Some(middle),
    Ordering::Greater => start = middle
}
```

#### Implicit `return`

At the end, it might be clearer to use the implicit return form:

```
if array[start] == key {
    Some(start)
} else if array[end] == key {
    Some(end)
} else {
    None
}
```

### Addendum: Tests

To make sure I didn't break your code while making these changes, I wrote a test. Tests are good to have (not that this is a particularly good test).

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_find() {
        assert_eq!(find(&[2, 4, 5, 7, 11, 12, 17], 5), Some(2));
        assert_eq!(find(&[], 5), None);
        assert_eq!(find(&[2, 4, 5, 7, 11, 12, 17], 6), None);
        assert_eq!(find(&[-63, -42, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 11, 12, 17, 17, 18], 12), Some(8));

        call_find(&[-10, -7, 0, 2, 4, 4, 5, 16, 27, 37, 38, 40, 40, 40, 40, 63, 628, 844, 10000000, 41230456]);
    }

    fn call_find(array: &[i32]) {
        for i in 0..array.len() {
            assert_eq!(array[find(array, array[i]).unwrap()], array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```